# New at Python need some guidance with IF statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

Q: Code runs but only prints the else statement...
   Any help is appreciated.

```
fruit = str()
favorite_fruits = ["mango", "kiwi", "pineapple"]
if fruit in favorite_fruits is "mango":
    print('You really like ' + fruit + '.')
if fruit in favorite_fruits is "kiwi":
    print('You really like ' + fruit + '.')
if fruit in favorite_fruits is "pineapple":
    print('You really like ' + fruit + '.')
if fruit in favorite_fruits is "apple":
    print('You really like' + fruit + '.')
else:
    print('Your going to starve.')
```

Comment: `fruit in favorite_fruits is "apple"` is not going to do anything meaningful, but I can't even guess what you thought it would mean, especially considering apple isn't in that list.

Comment: The apple reference was just to show that it would not print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str()` returns `''` every time. So `fruit` is always `''` which doesn't satisfy any of the `if` statements.

Also your if statements are off. You can just check if `fruit` is in `favorite_fruits` and then print:

```
fruit = "mango"
favorite_fruits = ["mango", "kiwi", "pineapple"]

if fruit in favorite_fruits:
    print('You really like ' + fruit + '.')
else:
    print('Your going to starve.')
```

If you want user input then use [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) instead of hard coding `fruit`.